# Get the REST method to work

Tags: development, jquery

Why the following code does not work? What do I need to do?

```
<script src="<MyServerName>/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="<MyServerName>/SiteAssets/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
         var listUrl =  "http://<MyServerName>/subsite/lists/getbytitle(‘products’)/items";
        $.ajax({  

    url: listUrl,    
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
    success: function(data) { 
     alert('success');                                  
     for (var i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++)  
     { 
       var dataCategory = data.d.results[i];   
       alert(dataCategory.Title); 
     } 
   }

   });  
 });  

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `_api/web` directive in the url:

```
var listUrl = "http://<MyServerName>/subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('products')/items"
```